# How do I get rid of the options in Photoshop's save dialog window

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Any idea how to get rid of those extra options in the window.

I remember doing this a while back, but now I've forgotten how I did it.

I've checked photoshop preferences and can't find any settings.

[image]

Comment: If you use an action or a script, you don't even have to see any dialog.

Answer (score 0):

In the Mac OS.. click the **up arrow** next to the drop down menu for the location to hide the file directory contents:

[image]

This ***may*** be what you are referring to.

I do not believe there is a way to hide the format options. They are imperative to any and every save operation.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to hide the options in the red highlight.  I know there's a way to do it somehow.  Thanks for answering though.